# Using CSS transitions to animate the position of SVG elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'd like to use CSS transitions to animate the position of SVG elements.

However - it looks like this works on some SVG elements (e.g., rect), but not on others (e.g. text):

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var x = Math.random() * 450;
  document.querySelector("rect").setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
  document.querySelector("text").setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
}
```

```css
rect {
  transition: all 700ms ease-in-out;
}

text {
  transition: all 700ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="100">
  <rect x="100" y="10" width="30" height="30" fill="blue" stroke="none"/>
  <text x="100" y="80" fill="red" stroke="none">Hello</text>
</svg>
<br>
<button>animate</button>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this? (ideally, without using JavaScript or a library like GreenSock).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use translation instead:

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var x = Math.random() * 250;
  document.querySelector("rect").setAttributeNS(null, "transform","translate("+x+")");
  document.querySelector("text").setAttributeNS(null, "transform","translate("+x+")");
}
```

```css
rect {
  transition: all 700ms ease-in-out;
}

text {
  transition: all 700ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="100">
  <rect x="100" y="10" width="30" height="30" fill="blue" stroke="none"/>
  <text x="100" y="80" fill="red" stroke="none">Hello</text>
</svg>
<br>
<button>animate</button>
```

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. That definitely works, and meets the parameters of my question, so I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer. However, in my actual application - the SVG elements are moving under a mask, and the transform seems to cause unintended side-effects. (I.e., when you apply a transform - elements that *should* be within the mask don't appear when they should). That's why I was hoping to get this to work by animating *x*, rather than *x + transform/translate*.

Comment: @mattstuehler you can probably then elaborate this issue (here on within another question) and we can help you find a solution ;)

Comment: Temani - here's an example with a mask: https://jsfiddle.net/n3v1wox6/. You can see that the mask is not working when I use transform + translate. In other words, and element that *looks* like it should be under the mask *isn't* actually under the mask when you apply the transform.

Comment: Temani - another thing I just noticed... In Chrome - animating the *x* property of the rect element works, but not for the text element. Using the transform property - it works for both elements. However - in Safari - the transform property doesn't work at all, for either element.

Comment: @mattstuehler this seems intresting, I suggest you to update your whole question with this code and add more explanation of the issue ... it will be a lot better that you basic question actually because you simply show us the visible part of the iceberg ;)

Comment: @mattstuehler yes SVG element are tricky and not handled the same cross browser that's why I suggest you to make your question more in-depth by adding more code and relevant description ;)

Comment: Actually Chrome is at odds with the spec. SVG 2 states that for `<text>` x/y attributes are [not presentation attributes](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#TSpanAttributes). Quote: "In SVG 2, the `text` and `tspan` `x` and `y` attributes are not presentation attributes and cannot be set via CSS." The background is that the attributes actually accept _lists_ of values.

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution is to use `transform`, as Temani said.

> However, in my actual application - the SVG elements are moving under a mask, and the transform seems to cause unintended side-effects.

That is because the transform on an element also applies to the other attributes that are applied to it. Such as a mask.  The fix is to move the mask to a parent group so that it is unaffected by the transform

```
<g mask="url(#mask1)">
  <rect id="rect2" x="0" y="60" width="20" height="20" fill="blue" stroke="none"/>
  <text id="text2" x="0" y="100" fill="red" stroke="none">Hello</text>
</g>
```

Full example:

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var x = Math.random() * 450;
/*   document.querySelector("rect").setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
  document.querySelector("text").setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
   */ 
  document.getElementById("rect1").setAttributeNS(null, "x",x);
  document.getElementById("text1").setAttributeNS(null, "x",x);

  document.getElementById("rect2").setAttributeNS(null, "transform","translate("+x+")");
  document.getElementById("text2").setAttributeNS(null, "transform","translate("+x+")");

}
```

```css
rect {
  transition: all 700ms ease-in-out;
}

text {
  transition: all 700ms ease-in-out;
}
svg {
 border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask1" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="200">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect id="rect1" x="0" y="10" width="20" height="20" fill="blue" stroke="none" mask="url(#mask1)"/>
  <text id="text1" x="0" y="50" fill="red" stroke="none" mask="url(#mask1)">Hello</text>
  <g mask="url(#mask1)">
    <rect id="rect2" x="0" y="60" width="20" height="20" fill="blue" stroke="none"/>
    <text id="text2" x="0" y="100" fill="red" stroke="none">Hello</text>
  </g>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="none" stroke="lime" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
<br>
<button>animate</button>
<p>
The green outline shows the position of the mask rect
</p>
```

Comment: Paul, Thank you - your answer *perfectly* solves the problem I was having with transform and the masks. The only problem I have left (unless I'm making a mistake) is that this only seems to work on Chrome. (In Safari and Firefox, the elements move as expected, and appear correctly under the mask, but are not animated). I guess this just means we don't yet have a solid, cross-browser way of animating SVG properties with CSS?

Comment: This is because in SVG 1.1 does not consider `transform` a styleable property (see [Appendix N of the SVG 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#chapter-propidx)).  That changed in SVG 2, but browsers are still implementing the SVG 2 changes.  Only Chrome (and other webkit browsers) have implemented the change that makes `transform` and some other attributes into stylable properties.  If you need this to work on all browsers **now**, you will need to use another method. For example with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can also achive this by **jquery**

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var x = Math.random() * 250;
    $('rect').attr("transform","translate("+x+")");
    $('text').attr("transform","translate("+x+")");
});
```

```css
rect {
  transition: all 700ms ease-in-out;
}

text {
  transition: all 700ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100">
  <rect x="100" y="10" width="30" height="30" fill="blue" stroke="none"/>
  <text x="100" y="80" fill="red" stroke="none">Hello</text>
</svg>
<br>
<button>animate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! However - this doesn't appear to work on Safari/Mac (it does work on Chrome/Mac). Also - unless I'm mistaken - jQuery is just using JavaScript to animate the position, which misses out on the benefit of GPU-acceleration that you can get with CSS transitions. Do you know if that's correct? Most important - I'm hoping to solve this without having to load any additional libraries.